# networkx- can't find cut_size

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I am trying to use networkx.cut_size according to  [documentation](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cuts.cut_size.html)

```
import networkx as nx 

G = nx.barbell_graph(3, 0)
S={0}
print nx.cut_size(G, S)
```

and I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cut_size'
```

networkx: 1.11

I am trying to understand what am I missing here. do I use the right version? right path to cut_size?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  Perhaps follow the link in the documentation to the code and define your own function to do this.

Comment: good advice. thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have an older version?  Your code works correctly with the 2.0 development version.